# Enable developer options on LG Stylo 4

Tags: lg, developer-options

The following is not working on my LG Stylo 4

> To enable Developer options you have to go to About Phone (or About phone > Software info) and tap Build number 7 times.

The reason being is I don't have an "About Phone" option in Settings.

How to enable the developer options on LG Style 4?

Comment: Can you show us your Settings in a screenshot ? On some phone the option may be different

Comment: Ok, tell me what your last option fron the settings looks like?

Comment: settings is the last option

Comment: The settings has a couple of options. The settings should have a GEAR icon

Comment: my bad, SYSTEM is the last option

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

From the Verizon [support](https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-161571/) page :

To enable Developer Options, navigate to: Apps > Settings > About phone > Software info then tap Build number seven times.

Ensure the Developer options switch (located in the upper-right) is turned on

Tap USB debugging to enable or disable.

Enabled when a check mark is present.

If presented with Allow USB debugging? screen, tap OK.